# How to fill a combobox from a matrix 2 dimensions in java

Tags: java, combobox

i want to fill a combo box with values from a matrix 2 dimensions in java. For example, I have a string

`[][] s;` with

```
s[0][0]=cp1; 
s[0][1]=30; 
s[0][2]=0;
s[1][0]=cp2;
s[1][1]=50; 
s[1][2]=1500;
```

i need to fill a combo box with values `cp1` and `cp2` and

```
if clicking on cp1 
    it shows the values 30 and 0 in 2 textboxes
else if clicking cp2 
    it shows 50 and 1500 in these textboxes.
```

I have tried code to fill a combobox, but i didn't succeed. Please, if you have any idea help me. Thanks in advance .

Comment: Please format your source code. This is hardly readable. Also please show your approach.

Comment: Do you want help with the combobox implementation logic? Or do you want to know how you can get the appropriate values from the array?

Comment: @Hirak i need to know how to get the appropriate values from the array

Answer (score 1):

Create a class that stores each entry.

```
class Entry <A,B> {
    A a;
    B b;
```

And set the toString method to only use the first field.

```
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        a.toString();
    }
}
```

You can then put an array of these objects into the combobox, and they will be displayed only by what is in field `a`.

You can then use

```
B value = combobox.getItemAt(combobox.getSelectedIndex()).b;
```

to get the value of the highlighted element.

This is a general solution, in your question it looks like you need more than two fields in the entry class, so just add those in.